# Linq query in C# to retrieve the positive numbers

Tags: c#

We have the list which contains both positive and negative numbers. How can we retrieve only positive numbers and create the new list with only positive numbers using Linq?

Answer (score 9):

Let's say `numbers` is the list of number.

```
var positiveNumbers = numbers.Where(x => x > 0 ).ToList();
```